# Access denied for user while executing the GRANT command in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

grant select ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' with GRANT OPTION;
grant select ON *.* TO 'username'@'IPaddress' with GRANT OPTION;

All the above statements errors out with the Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'user'@'IPAddress' to database

FYI I am logged in as a user with all the permissions -- 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* '

1. With the current user I am able to perform all operation , but I want to add more users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be logged in with a user that has `WITH GRANT OPTION` as well, such as root@'localhost'. Otherwise, you can do everything else, BUT create new user and issue new grants/permissions.

> GRANT OPTION   Enable privileges to be granted to or removed from other accounts. Levels: Global, database, table, procedure.

You can read more here are [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_grant-option).